# Deeplinking apps in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

We have a case where we want to navigate between apps, case where

1. triggering a payment will open the payment app
2. once the payment is complete it should navigate back to the original app.

I have found few theoretical solution for (1), can use Android Intent(I hope I'm right here), or use services like [https://deeplink.me](https://deeplink.me/). Which navigate to the payment app, I assume here that I can pass some complex data along with the request to navigate to the correct page on my app.

For problem 2, I'm yet identify a solution, Do I have include Intent filter in the source app too? say the source app uses the payment app's sdk and is there a way I could pass back the response an HTTP response which the source app can use to navigate to the right page (payment success or failure).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: an Android Intent can be used to open another app ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)). Facebook's [Applinks standard](http://applinks.org) can also do this, as can the [Branch.io](https://branch.io/features/#app-connections) service (amongst many other things). Deeplink.me AppWords is a neat concept, though it appears to be bid-based and I can't see a way to open a *specific* app on demand.

However, unless there is a **need** to use an external app for this, why not just integrate something like the [Stripe Android SDK](https://stripe.com/android-pay), or PayPal's [braintree SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v2) or [native SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) directly into your app? That way you don't even have to worry about passing data around externally and you retain end-to-end control of the process. Seems like a far more elegant solution!